# 404 on assets when using Laravel Vite + Sail

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-sail, laravel-vite

I wanted to try out Sail on my Windows machine, however, after installing Breeze on a brand new installation of Laravel and running `sail npm run dev` I received a 404 in the browser for `http://localhost/css/app.css` and `http://localhost/js/app.js` when navigating to `http://localhost/login` on my Windows host.

- Laravel Vite Plugin Version: v0.6.0
- Laravel Version: v9.19
- Node Version: v16.18.0
- NPM Version: v8.19.2
- Host operating system: Windows
- Web Browser & Version: Firefox 106.0.2 (64-bit)

I am able to navigate to `http://localhost:5173/` in the browser which displays the informative message, so we know that it is working. When using inspect element on the `/login` page the following URLs are returned as a 404: `http://localhost/css/app.css` & `http://localhost/js/app.js`.

In previous attempts I did try adding the following snippet to my `vite.config.js` file, however, it made no difference and the problem persisted.

```
  server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    },
```

This is a fresh install of Docker, WSL2 and Laravel with Breeze so in theory, it should all be working, but clearly, something is awry.

The result is seeing this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRZws.png

If anybody could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!